# Python not appending data with pandas in Excel Workbook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am writing a python program to fetch data from three different excel workbooks and append it to different sheets in a fourth workbook with pre-existing data. Although when i am running the code there are no errors and the excel file's date of modification is changing, the data is not actually getting appended to the workbook. Please help me out:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#reading all three ticket excel sheets
df1 = pd.read_excel("sheet a.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("sheet b.xlsx")
df3 = pd.read_excel("sheet c.xlsx")

#Creating Panadas Excel writer using xlsxwriter as engine
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"main_excel.xlsx", engine = "openpyxl")

writer.book = load_workbook(r"main_excel.xlsx")
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}

#reading existing file
reader = pd.read_excel(r"main_excel.xlsx")

#converting dataframes to xlsxwriter excel object
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name ="sheet a", index = False, header = False,startrow=len(reader)+1)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name ="sheet b", index = False, header = False,startrow=len(reader)+1)
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name ="sheet c", index = False, header = False,startrow=len(reader)+1)

writer.close()
```

The sheets a,b,c share the same names with sheets in sheet d.

Comment: I forgot to mention the writer.save() here in the question. It is present in the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your code works on my system.

It first pulls the first sheet of each excel file, then appends it as a new sheet in `main_excel.xlsx`, but with `len(reader)+1` blank rows at the top of each new sheet, where `reader` is the first sheet of main_excel.xlsx and `len(reader)` is the number of non-blank rows in that sheet. Is that what you're going for?

If you don't want the blank rows, you can skip reading the existing file and drop the `startrow` argument from `.to_excel(...)`.

You say the sheets a,b,c share the same names with sheets in sheet d, in which case "sheet a" through "sheet c" in `main_excel.xlsx` would be overwritten.

Comment: I rechecked and modified the code this way:
`sheets = writer.book.sheetnames
reader1 = pd.read_excel(r"main_excel.xlsx", "sheet a")
reader2 = pd.read_excel(r"main_excel.xlsx", "sheet b")
reader3 = pd.read_excel(r"main_excel.xlsx", "sheet c")

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name =sheets[0], index = False, header = False,startrow=len(reader1)+1)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name =sheets[2], index = False, header = False,startrow=len(reader2)+1)
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name =sheets[4], index = False, header = False,startrow=len(reader3)+1)

writer.save()
writer.close()
`
Thanks